# Deployment org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am trying to deploy a Java EE 6 Rest application to a remote Glassfish Server but keep getting this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess(AbstractSessionImpl.java:259)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:87)
```

However the code runs perfectly when deployed locally.

And the remote Glassfish server already has an application running on it with this same version of hibernate so I'm confused as to what can be causing this.

Any help appreciated.

Regards